# How to open an electron app on linux using php?

Tags: node.js, linux, electron

I want to open an app that the client has installed, it's an electron app, but i can't seem to figure out how to get it to open an app.

I have a URI Handler in electron:

```
protocol.registerHttpProtocol('snorainstore', (req, cb) => {
  const url = req.url
  var executablePath = `${appdir}/include/manage.sh`;
  if (url == "install") {
    var parameters = [`--install ${apptomanage}`];
    child(executablePath, parameters, function(err, data) {
         console.log(err)
         console.log(data.toString());
    });
  }
})
```

Comment: So, you want to open the Electron app, which has a handler for `snorainstore://` registered, from a PHP web application? Or what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: i want to have the app load a specific function based on a url passed to the app, i.e: "snorainstore://install/disweb", then have electron open the manage.sh script included with the store and then pass the arguments to the script.